# OutOfMemoryError when loading an animation .xml

Tags: android, android-animation, drawable, android-drawable

I have the following `ImageView`:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.create_user);
```

My `create_user` drawable looks like this:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">    
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/create_user_0" android:duration="500" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/create_user_1" android:duration="500" />
</animation-list>
```

But when the `.xml` is being set in `imageView.setBacgroundResource(R.drawable.create_user)`, it launches the following exception:

```
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at  android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at  android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:873)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2970)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:15697)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.facephi.sdk.ui.FragmentCreatingStructure.onCreateView(FragmentCreatingStructu re.java:29)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
02-04 10:49:07.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1379):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have to say that I've been using this animation for a looong time. And yesterday was the first time it started crashing.

I can't imagine what's going on at this point... Can anyone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

**NOTE:** It says  `Out of memory on a 638416-byte allocation` before the mistake is launched.

**NOTE2:** It also says this several times before the application crashes.

```
02-04 11:23:56.179: I/dalvikvm(7266): "Binder_1" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
02-04 11:23:56.179: I/dalvikvm(7266):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x427f2200 self=0x4192fcd0
02-04 11:23:56.179: I/dalvikvm(7266):   | sysTid=7277 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1100151432
02-04 11:23:56.179: I/dalvikvm(7266):   | state=R schedstat=( 504400204 75428596 671 ) utm=34 stm=15 core=2
02-04 11:23:56.179: I/dalvikvm(7266):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
02-04 11:23:56.179: E/Camera-JNI(7266): Couldn't allocate byte array for JPEG data
02-04 11:23:56.239: I/dalvikvm-heap(7266): Clamp target GC heap from 71.012MB to 64.000MB
02-04 11:23:56.239: D/dalvikvm(7266): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-04 11:23:56.239: D/dalvikvm(7266): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 21K, 3% free 63352K/65192K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
02-04 11:23:56.239: I/dalvikvm-heap(7266): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 460816-byte allocation
02-04 11:23:56.259: I/dalvikvm-heap(7266): Clamp target GC heap from 71.012MB to 64.000MB
02-04 11:23:56.259: D/dalvikvm(7266): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
02-04 11:23:56.259: D/dalvikvm(7266): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 3% free 63352K/65192K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
02-04 11:23:56.259: E/dalvikvm-heap(7266): Out of memory on a 460816-byte allocation.
```

Comment: How big are your images in kBytes?

Comment: Try to replace `imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.create_user);` to `imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.create_user));`

Comment: Like 50kb more or less. They are pretty small...

Comment: @JoanColmenero I changed it, but it still crashes...

Comment: It is giving the same error?

Comment: If you're using Android Studio, have you tried using Memory monitor? Maybe you're loading drawable multiple times.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse. Any way to do so with it?

Comment: DDMS or ADM - http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: @skywall You were right, I was loading drawable multiple times... I reviewed, and... done! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **android:largeHeap="true",** in the manifest to see if this solves it.

Or Use api **inSampleSize** of **bitmapfactory** to sample the images.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of error once but when I re sized my images it got resolved.
Try to re-size your images.

Comment: I tried your solution. I resized them, even if they were only 50Kb. From a 400x350px image to 300x280px. But it's still launching the same error...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to resize your images to adapt them to the exact size of the view, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). You can even try using libraries like [universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) which make this task easier.